# How to force OpenAL to interface with pulseaudio in libgdx? (works on GNOME but not on i3)

Tags: libgdx, alsa, openal, pulseaudio, i3

I have a problem with openAL and pulseaudio. When I run the original generated libgdx code it works fine. However when I start my volume control GUI (pavucontrol) I get a message saying pulse audio has not been started. However if I am to start Firefox and play an audio file *before* running the libgdx code, then I run the libgdx code it prints this error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) alsa_open_playback: Could not open playback device 'default': Device or resource busy
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not locate OpenAL library.
```

It seems that openAL is talking directly to alsa rather than the pulseaudio server. This is on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. When I run the same code on my Fedora 29 workstation or my old laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 then the libgdx code runs perfectly and will overlap with the audio from Firefox as well as being recognized by pavucontrol as a process named "java".

EDIT: When I log in to my session using GNOME instead of my i3 windows manager it works! Please explain how to make this work on i3.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same issue. It seems pulseaudio was not started. Start it explicitly via ~/.config/i3/config:

```
exec_always --no-startup-id /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
```